# Cannot retrieve value from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, information-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve data from my tables. But I'm having trouble with that.

I have tables:

**Owners**:

[image: Owners]

**Patients**:

[image: Patient]

**Referral**:

[image: referral]

**Treatments**:

[image: treatments]

**Hospitals**:

[image: hospitals]

**Hospitals_treatments**:

[image: hospitals_treatments]

How can I select the owner details for patients that have been referred to the Bourneville Animal Hospital? Can anyone provide me solution for this?

I tried with following query but it returns all owners multiple times to 160. I tdoesn't seem to be working.

```
select 
    isnull(o.title, ' ') + ' ' + isnull(o.first_name, ' ') + ' ' + 
    isnull(o.last_name, ' ') as Owner, 
    isnull(o.address, ' ') as Address   
from 
    Owners o, appointment_details ad, referral r,treatments t, hospitals_treatments ht, hospitals h,patients p
where 
    r.treatmentstreatment_id = (select TOP 1 ht.treatmentstreatment_id 
                                from hospitals_treatments ht 
                                where ht.hospitalshospital_id = (select hospital_id  
                                                                 from hospitals 
                                                                  where name='Bourneville Animal Hospital Middlesex')) 
  and r.appointment_detailsappointment_id = ad.appointment_id;
```

Table queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Owners 
(
  owner_id   INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  title      varchar(255) NULL, 
  first_name varchar(255) NULL, 
  last_name  varchar(255) NULL, 
  address    varchar(255) NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (owner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE appointment_details 
(
  appointment_id     INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  appointment_date   datetime NULL, 
  details            text NULL, 
  patientspatient_id INT NOT NULL, 
  vetsvet_id         INT NOT NULL, 
  cost               varchar(255) NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (appointment_id)
);

CREATE TABLE referral 
(
   referral_id                       INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
   sessions                          int NULL, 
   appointment_detailsappointment_id INT NOT NULL, 
   treatmentstreatment_id            INT NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (referral_id)
);

CREATE TABLE treatments 
(
    treatment_id INT identity NOT NULL, 
    name         varchar(255) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (treatment_id)
);

CREATE TABLE hospitals 
(
    hospital_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    name        varchar(255) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (hospital_id)
);

CREATE TABLE hospitals_treatments 
(
  hospitalshospital_id   INT  NOT NULL, 
  treatmentstreatment_id INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (hospitalshospital_id, treatmentstreatment_id)
);

ALTER TABLE patients 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKpatients296497 
    FOREIGN KEY (Ownersowner_id) 
    REFERENCES Owners (owner_id);

ALTER TABLE referral 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKreferral97180 
    FOREIGN KEY (appointment_detailsappointment_id)
    REFERENCES appointment_details (appointment_id);

ALTER TABLE hospitals_treatments 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKhospitals_169422 
    FOREIGN KEY (hospitalshospital_id)
    REFERENCES hospitals (hospital_id);

ALTER TABLE hospitals_treatments 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKhospitals_718862 
    FOREIGN KEY (treatmentstreatment_id) 
    REFERENCES treatments (treatment_id);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet yourself?

Comment: Yeah tried it with following:

Comment: `select isnull(o.title,' ')+ ' '+ isnull(o.first_name,' ')+' '+ isnull(o.last_name,' ') as Owner, isnull(o.address,' ') as Address   
from Owners o, appointment_details ad, referral r,treatments t, hospitals_treatments ht, hospitals h,patients p
where r.treatmentstreatment_id=(select TOP 1 ht.treatmentstreatment_id from hospitals_treatments ht 
where ht.hospitalshospital_id=(select hospital_id from hospitals where name='Bourneville Animal Hospital Middlesex')) and
r.appointment_detailsappointment_id = ad.appointment_id;`

Comment: It just doesn't seem to be working

Comment: instead of providing images,please provide text going forward,so people can test ..You can also provide online link :http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Missing information: where is the connection between referral and patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on the table structure you have provided, try this, it will give the owners information you are looking for.

```
select DISTINCT
    isnull(o.title, ' ') + ' ' + isnull(o.first_name, ' ') + ' ' + 
    isnull(o.last_name, ' ') as Owner, 
    isnull(o.address, ' ') as Address   
from 
    Owners o
    inner join patients p on o.owner_id = p.Ownersowner_id  
    inner join appointment_details ad on ad.patientspatient_id = p.patient_id
    inner join referral r on r.appointment_detailsappointment_id = ad.appointment_id
where exists (  select 1
                from hospitals_treatments ht 
                inner join hospitals h ON h.hospital_id = ht.hospitalshospital_id
                where h.name='Bourneville Animal Hospital Middlesex'
                    AND ht.treatmentstreatment_id = r.treatmentstreatment_id 
            )
```